# PHP cURL hacking php authentication

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I have a website in a remote host with a normal php authentication to get to admin area of the site, i.e. login details are stored in db and user input are checked against it. I just started learning PHP cURL recently and did some experiments in my localhost. Using the get page function I was able to bypass the authentication of my remote website and get to the admin area.

PHP cURL:

```
$cSession = curl_init();


curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"http://myremotesite.com/admin/profit");
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$result = curl_exec($cSession);
echo $result;
```

I was expecting the to be redirected to the admin login. This seems like a serious security matter. I also should mention that my remote website is not using any form of `SiteLock`.

Comment: And what happens when you open that link manually?, probably the same, since you've probably never made a check to see if the admin is actually logged in.

Comment: It sounds like the web site isn't properly checking that you're really logged in. It needs to use a session variables to track this.

Comment: I do not see any code for cookies and no post action for the login. Can it be, you are only visiting?

Comment: I don't think there's any issue with your code, the problem is with the remote site.

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers    the check for sessions are right. I cannot access any admin page manualy.

Comment: @Barmar that's what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

The protected area / page / pages should have some level of verifying user is valid - ie: user logs in and a session cookie is set then check for that cookie. Also, if on an apache webserver perhaps you might use an .htaccess file as a secondary level of security for protected pages.

Comment: "The protected area / page / pages should have some level of verifying user is valid - ie: user logs in and a session cookie is set then check for that cookie."  That's the way it is. Now as for the .htaccess file can you elaborate better? do I need extra .htaccess just for the admin folder ? what should I include in it.

Comment: Yes, place a new .htaccess file in root level of admin folder - or whatever folder you wish to protect. Within that .htaccess file you will need to specify what type of authentication is required, the username / group and the path to the .htpasswd file.

If these pages are using some sort of verification ( cookies, session vars ) then there must be a problem if you were able to circumvent that with a simple curl request.